# How to pass data from controller to SignalR hub class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I working on a simple chat project. The project consist of two pages, one for log in and one for chatting. The controller of the log in page check the username and password of the user and if its correct, it store the user id and username in session["Info"].

The problem is that I can't get the username and user id from SignalR  hub class because session can't be used in hub class. So I need a way to pass data from the log in controller to the hub class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Standard ASP.NET security after that you can always get the user using standard ASP.NET features both from MVC controllers and SignalR or core business logic etc.

Comment: Use Windows or Forms authentication, The signalr context will then use them

Comment: Can you give an example please.

Comment: If you use windows authentication its just a matter of enabling windows auth. If you use forms read here http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/security/16-adding-security-and-membership.

Comment: From your Hub then use Context.User.Identity

Comment: The answer to this question should not be bounded with only the authentication issue. Any controller might want to make use of signalr hub class. Eg, when a restful endpoint called from a client, might want to notify clients. You would rather provide a general solution.

Comment: First off all, its bad practice calling Hubs from domain code, you should abstract SignalR from any domain code. Second if you use the core security functions in ASP.NET or later it WILL just work. If you need protect a method from being invoked by action that does not have the correct authorization there are built in support for that too.